# Simple way to print a vector and string in one return value in R

Tags: r

I am using a validation function within R Shiny to try to output an error. However, I can't seem to do a rather simple thing, which is return this error all in one line.

The output is both a vector of 1 or more values and a string before those values that introduces the error. The output that I would like is the following:
"String of text element1, element2, element3."

The methods that I have tried are the following:

Paste:

```
paste("Tall",c(1,2,3)
```

Output: Tall 1 Tall 2 Tall 3

Paste:

```
paste("Tall",paste(c(1,2,3))
```

Output: Tall 1 Tall 2 Tall 3

Paste with

Sprintf:

```
sprintf("Tall %s",c(1,2,3))
```

Output: Tall 1 Tall 2 Tall 3

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try with `paste("Tall",c(1,2,3), collapse= ', ')`

Comment: To clarify the solution was a bit different than above: paste("Tall",paste(c(1,2,3), collapse= ', '))

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: "Tall 1, 2, 3" not "Tall 1, Tall 2, Tall 3"

Comment: But, you got the result with `paste("Tall",paste(c(1,2,3), collapse= ', '))`

Comment: Correct. I got the expected output with that.

Comment: In your post, the description was a bit confusing `"String of text element1, element2, element3."`